# Is the data structure union sockunion only for FreeBSD or also for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, freebsd

Is the data structure `union sockunion` only for FreeBSD or is it also valid for Linux? If its only for FreeBSD then what is the equivalent in Linux?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exposed in /usr/include in FreeBSD either, although it exists there within libc's internal source code.

Some other software, like Zebra ships it as well.

How did you stumble upon it?

Comment: some developed an application for FreeBSD and i need to make it work on linux. Thanks!

Comment: @Pheonix7: And the union sockunion is not defined in the application source ?

Comment: yes its defined as: union sockunion {
 struct  sockaddr sa;
 struct  sockaddr_in sin;
 struct  sockaddr_in6 sin6;
 struct  sockaddr_storage ss;
}; can i use this as it is iin linux?

Comment: I trued launching this application on my linux system and it seems that the sockunion works. While debbuging i can see the correct address values. How is that possible? Does that mean that i can leave it and it will work. Consider that there is a lot of code behind and if i had to change it i would know where to start. appreciate it

Comment: @Pheonix7: Yes, if the union is defined in your source code, you should be able to use it as it is. That is possible because those structs that it consists of all do exist in both Linux and FreeBSD.